# Python OpenPyXL, Assign a Value to a Range

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using Python and openpyxl to work with an Excel Spreadsheet and want to assign a value to a named range (Of a single cell) on a sheet.  What's the syntax?  For instance, if the sheet is, "Dog," and the single celled range is "dog_name?"

I was expecting something like wb["Dog"]["dog_name"] = "Snoopy" but, that's a fail.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: ValueError: dog_name is not a valid coordinate or range.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of syntax that I got to work:

```
wb["Dog"][wb.defined_names["dog_name"].value[-4:]] = "Snoopy"
```

It strips out the cell address of the range to use as the address for the assignment.  Seems inelegant to me so, please post alternatives.